# How to refresh a collectionView when click on button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to refresh my collectionView When I click on a button and make the app continue to run while the collectionview is filled

Here is my Xaml :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="WordSList" ItemsLayout="Vertical"    >
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
         <DataTemplate>

              <StackLayout >
                   <Label  Text="{Binding Word1}"   />
                    </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>

     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

What I would like :

```
List<MyClass> MyWordsList;
ObservableCollection<MyClass> datasource;
int ndx = 100;
 public void OnRefreshing_MyCollection_View()
        {
          // refresh the collection view without making the app waiting for it to be filled
          MyWordsList  =  await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();
         WordSList.ItemsSource = datasource = new ObservableCollection<MyClass (MyWordsList.Take(ndx));

        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what don't you understand how to do?  You have the refresh function.  Do you need help with the button click event?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes would like to activate the refresh event of collectionView when clicking on a button

Comment: call `OnRefreshing_MyCollection_View()` from your button click handler

Comment: Yes and is there a way to make the function OnRefreshing_MyCollection_View() run on background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the RefreshView of Xamarin.Forms like in this example of James Montemagno:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/refreshview-xamarin-forms/

You have a property IsRefreshing which you set on the beginning of your refreshing-method. After refreshing you set it to false.

```
<RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
             Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <!-- Add ItemTemplate Here -->
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>

void ExecuteRefreshCommand()
{
    Items.Clear();
    Items.Add(new Item { Text = "Refreshed Data", Description = "Whoa!" });
    
    // Stop refreshing
    IsRefreshing = false;
}
```

In the example its an drag-down-element in your collection view. But you can also do this with a button event and an async method to load your data.